# How do I protect myself from AWS Lambda abuse?

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm creating a serverless website using AWS Lambda, but I'm a bit concerned about potential abuse. How do I protect myself against a user who queries my endpoint a million times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API Gateway supports throttling. The defaults are reasonable, but you can alter them however you like. The throttle settings in the console are under the `Stages` tab of you APIs. There's more info here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html